# How do I code this javascript function to display two+ fieldsets when a particular type is selected

Tags: javascript

I have a webform, in this example, user selection a project type from a dropdown field and various sections hide/display based on the type selected.  The id's in the array below are the fieldset id's and the value is what is selected in the dropdown field.

Now here is the issue.  I have a client that wants **two** sections/fieldset to appear when a particular project is selected. [this option could apply to various project types]. **For example**, if I select '**Brochure**' as the project type the client wants the **Brochure section/fieldset to appear as well as a fieldset called "Brief Details"**.  It's id is '556'.

If I add "{id : '556', value:'Brochure'}" to the array below, the "Brief Details" section/fieldset **will display**, **but** it **hides** the "Brochure" fieldset that should also be showing in this case.  I do see why this is happening, but can't figure out how to make this javascript work.

So how do I code this, **using the code base below** [if project type selected equals brochure, show fieldset 556 **and** 159]

```
var projectTypes = new Array (
    {id : '123', value:'Banner'},
    {id : '456', value:'Ad'},
    {id : '789', value:'Graphics'},
    {id : '987', value:'Billboard'},
    {id : '654', value:'Booklet'},
    {id : '321', value:'Tickets'},
    {id : '147', value:'Window'},
    {id : '159', value:'Brochure'}
    );

/*function below occurs onChange event of project type dropdown:*/
refreshSections(project_type);  

/*
 *  Function used to hide/show sections based on selected project type
 */
function refreshSections(selectedType) 
{   
    for (var i = 0; i < projectTypes.length; i++) 
    {
        if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType) 
        {
            document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using instead of a single id an array

```
{id : ['159','556'], value:'Brochure'}
```

and then in the function code you could do

```
if (projectTypes[i].value === selectedType) {
  if (typeof projectTypes[i].id == "object") {
    var targets = typeof projectTypes[i].id;
    for (var j = 0, l = targets.length; j < l; j++) {
      document.getElementById("section-"+ targets[j]).style.display = '';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = 'none';
}
```

I did not deeply test it... you could maybe add a[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with some markup and JS code so it would be easier to check a solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much freedom you have to modify the code/html, but given reasonable access to the relevant sections, I would be inclined to add another value to your projectTypes array. The implementation doesn't necessarily have to look like this, but for example:

```
var projectTypes = new Array (
    {id : '556', value:'Brief Details', showSections: [556, 159]}
);
```

add a common classname across all 'hideable sections':

```
<div id="section-156" class="hideable-section"><!--content--></div>
```

and then modify your function to use that property as an override:

```
function refreshSections(selectedType) {   
    var i, j;
    //hide everything by default (something like document.getElementsByClassName('hideable-section')
    for (i = 0; i < projectTypes.length; i++) {
        if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType) {
            if(projectTypes[i].showSections != null) {
                for(j = 0; j < projectTypes[i].showSections.length; j++){
                    document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].showSections[j].toString()).style.display = '';
                }
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
            }
        }
    }   
}
```